# Create task in PhpStorm which loads into Youtrack as an issue

Tags: phpstorm, youtrack

I'm wondering if it is possible to create a task in PhpStorm(or other ide) and have it sync/upload to Youtrack as an issue?

I can do it the other way by creating an issue in Youtrack and having it appear in phpStorm, but I am wanting the above.

Thanks

Comment: I don't use YouTrack, and there doesn't seem to be a similar option for Asana, so I will suggest that you submit a feature request to JetBrains for this.